# How to Centre & Zoom a Google map V3 on it's markers using PHP (no Javascript!)?

Tags: php, google-maps, zooming, center

I have a Google map with several markers displayed, typically around six. I want the map scaled and zoomed to fit all six markers and hopefully centred on them too. I am using Google maps V3.

It's not an uncommon problem, even here on Stackoverflow, but all the solutions I've seen employ Javascript. For various reasons I want to use PHP only, not least of which is I have everything working with PHP and it shouldn't be necessary to use another technology for part of the solution; it's messy and difficult to maintain. So for clarity let me repeat, I am looking for a PHP solution here!

Here's a snapshot of what I have right now:

```
// 1st marker
$lat=$_SESSION['map_lat_1']; // latitude  
$lng=$_SESSION['map_lng_1']; // longitude
$isclickable='true';
$title=$_SESSION['map_title_1'];
$info=$_SESSION['map_info_1'];
$icon='mapclass/my-marker.png';
$map->addMarker($lat,$lng,$isclickable,$title,$info,$icon);

// 2nd marker
$lat=$_SESSION['map_lat_2']; // latitude  
$lng=$_SESSION['map_lng_2']; // longitude
$isclickable='true';
$title=$_SESSION['map_title_2'];
$info=$_SESSION['map_info_2'];
$icon='mapclass/my-marker.png';
$map->addMarker($lat,$lng,$isclickable,$title,$info,$icon);
```

So I feed the calls to addMarker with data garnered from numerous variables, some session variables, then I do the call:

```
echo $map->showmap();
```

And it all works well. Except I have a very rough 'rule of thumb' algorithm I devised to try to guess at the zoom level etc. It's hit 'n miss at best. I'm sure there must be a PHP way of accessing additional functions to set the framing and zoom factors to whatever's needed for any given case, but what are they and where do they fit into the scheme of things?

Your thoughts would be much appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438163/google-maps-api-v3-php-mysql - for the center point

Comment: What PHP library are you using? The Maps API itself is written in Javascript. So all interaction actully happens with Javascript. You must be using a library that just generates the required Javascript. Look in the docs for the library, maybe it has functions to do what you want.

Comment: Hi Barry Thank you for that. Doh! I had no idea that that's how PHP classes work, in this instance anyway. It's an obscure and I think very basic class called googlemap version 1.0.0.0 by Sandeep Kumar that I got from the PHP Classes website. I don't really understand Javascript much beyond basic hacks but it looks minimal inside. So given no choice, can I suddenly break into some Javascript mid-flow? I guess that's the only way forward, or a more extensive and equally friendly PHP class... if you know of one?